# Fixed point iteration involving integral $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k(x,t)f(x-t)dt+g(x)$.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, improper-integrals, roots, fixed-point-theorems

Let $g(x)$ and $k(x,t)$ be two known functions. Is it possible to uniquely solve for $f(x)$ that is defined as:

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k(x,t)f(x-t)dt+g(x) \tag{1}$$

I am looking for a numerical approach. One way that I was thinking of is formulating the above equation in a fixed-point interation framwork. Consider $f^{0}(x)$ is an initial guess of $f(x)$. Then,

$$f^{n+1}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k(x,t)f^{n}(x-t)dt+g(x) \tag{2}$$

provides an iterative approach to find $f(x)$. The question, however, I would like to get some inputs is:

**Question**: If this the right approach, what should be the initial guess $f^{0}(x)$?

If not, what is the right approach to address this problem?

Comment: You should compute the differential of this operator, and try to choose a point in a stable neighborhood where its norm is smaller than $1$

Comment: Thanks. What should I search for, to find some examples or references? Or can you provide one?

Comment: Any book about differential calculus? Maybe books about functional analysis cover this subject, I'm not so sure. But this one is actually easy, its differential is at every point $h \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^\infty k(x,t) h(t) dt$. What hypothesis do you have on $k$? is it of compact support?

Comment: A nice assumption would be for example $k$ has compact support and $\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty k(x,t) dt < 1$.

Comment: Consider k(x,t)=ce^(-(x+t)^2), for a constant c.

Comment: for $c < \sqrt{\pi}$ it will work

Comment: Do you mean, it will work for any $f^{0}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148443/discussion-between-julio-es-sui-glace-and-mirar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as a Fredholm integral equation. Specifically, using the change of variable $x - t = y$, the equation becomes
$$
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \tilde K(x,y) f(y)\,dy + g(x),
$$

where $\tilde K(x,y) = K(x,x-y)$. You'll find a lot about Fredholm equations.